# VoIP adapter unable to receive calls

Tags: voip, sip

I have my landline phone connected to a VoIP adapter, which works perfectly fine when I am making calls but doesn't work when I am receiving calls. The phone will ring like normal, but as soon as I pick up the call disconnects.

I analyzed the packets going through with Wireshark, and I found out that a SIP packet BYE request is being sent by my VoIP provider's server as soon as I pick up the phone. When the ringing first starts, I can see an INVITE request from the server, followed by my adapter sending a 100 TRYING, 180 RINGING, and 200 OK response. After that, the BYE gets sent, which presumably is the problem, but I have no idea why it is doing this or how to fix it.

The only thing that seems out of the ordinary with the packets is that the packets my adapter is sending contain the warning text "Detected NAT type is Port Restricted Cone NA", and I'm not sure what to do about this or if it is even the problem. I would guess that if the NAT wasn't working, then the SIP packets wouldn't be able to get through to my adapter, but I can see in Wireshark that the server and adapter are communicating just fine. Other than this, the packets seem fine, except of course for the BYE request right as the call starts.

I should also mention that I have had my VoIP service and adapter for a while, and this is only a recent issue that started after I changed my internet service provider. I also changed my modem, but I went back to my old modem once I noticed this problem and it didn't solve the issue. I would prefer to stay with my current ISP and VoIP provider if possible. What could be causing the BYE request, and how can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

This seems unusual and tricky to debug. If adapter has any kind of log - take a look at it.

Check if there is anything suspicious inside SDP offer in INVITE and SDP in 200/OK - compare this with outgoing call.

Timing between 200/OK and BYE might be point of interest - is BYE within miliseconds or is it delayed.

Try other device and/or softphone for comparison - even if they would also had problem they might be easier to debug with more detailed log.